# How does Higgs field transform when moving between inertial frames?

Tags: special-relativity, higgs

My naive understanding of the Higgs field is it's a bit like molasses and that's how particles "get" mass. In fact without the Higgs field, particles could travel at the speed of light. However, the problem I have with this is doesn't this imply a special reference frame? Given that objects travelling at the speed of light *relative* to a "stationary object" (in the rest frame of the stationary object) gain mass - my understanding is that is partially due to the massively increased flux of Higgs boson as they move through the Higgs field. However, in the rest frame of the moving particle there is no mass increase.

How does this work? If the analogy with molasses is correct then if the Higgs field transforms as per Lorentz then I can't see how you would get the flux increase which would lead to the increase in mass. So I'm guessing a different transformation is appropriate. What is this transformation?

Comment: if the Higgs mechanism just nails the intrinsic mass of the fundamental particles then when people say "the fundamental particles would travel at the speed of light if were not for the Higgs field" then are they just plain wrong? because I can't see how my question isn't relevant if that were the case.

Comment: The Higgs mechanism is not this non-trivial that one can see it from special relativity itself. At least some amount of QFT is needed to understand what is it people are talking about. All these confusions stem from reading pop-science books that try to oversimplify things but instead simply don't work (unless I knows what exactly it is).

Comment: The Higgs field isn't something with a "worldline" where you have to consider the relative motion of particles with respect to it. If you really want to keep the analogy, perhaps you could think of it as a coherent state of molasses particles of all possible momenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, you must specify what you mean a bit more clearly with your flakey molasses analogy: it hardly makes sense to me.

In non-fantasy physics terms, the Higgs field is a scalar, and its non-vanishing vacuum value *v* is Lorentz invariant and looks identical in every frame. The Yukawa term giving fermions a mass by coupling left/right chiral modes is Lorentz invariant, and the Higgs mechanism framework giving gauge bosons masses is also Lorentz covariant/invariant.

The term "gives mass" in physics means that setting the couplings to the Higgs, or its vacuum expectation  *v*, equal to zero ("turning them off") would yield zero masses for the affected particles. So zero Yukawa *g* or zero *v* for fermions would decouple left/right modes and the respective fermions would be massless. Zero *v* would yield  massless Ws and Z (messing with its coupling to them is trickier).

Can you specify perhaps what this odd business of luxons in molasses is about? [Ben Zimmer](https://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2012/07/14/metaphors-and-higgs-boson/UjdsEySmG63XIAcNN7LNSO/story.html) thought of it as the splinter on the banister of slippery metaphors.

Comment: right - so ignore flakey molasses! Ok then.